# Mutual Inclusion Error based off Virtual Class (C++)

Tags: c++, virtual

I have two classes that require a definition of each other to compile. Example:

```
Foo.h requires FooFunctions.h
Fuu.h requires FuuFunctions.h
FooFunctions.h requires Fuu.h
FuuFunctions.h requires Foo.h
```

Both Fuu and Foo are based off the same virtual class.
There are forward declarations of both classes Foo and Fuu in the implementation, but it throws a error 'allocation of incomplete type'

Comment: You should also show us the code where you are trying to allocate the incomplete type.

Comment: Forward declare each class in the headers, and in the actual implementation have the full definition.

Comment: Are you using compile guards?